# String to int invalid exceptions how to retrieve this column from db

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following code:

```
void combofill()
{
    String str = "server=RAVI;database=sampledb;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    String query = "select * from DentalLogin";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataReader dr;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(dr.Read())
         {

         string ut = dr.GetString("usertype");
         ComboBoxut.Items.Add(ut);

    }
}
```

I am getting error at `string ut=dr.GetString("usertype");` 
The error is:

> Cannot convert string to int

Answer (score 2):

[`GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects an integer value for column ordinal, You are passing it a string, *probably* a column name. Specify the correct column ordinal or use:

```
 string ut = Convert.ToString(dr["usertype"]);
```

Or if you want to use `GetString` then specify the column ordinal like:

```
 string ut = dr.GetString(0); //assuming 0 ordinal is for `usertype`
```

One more thing to add, enclosing your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` in [using statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). This will ensure their disposal after usage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GetString` method, you can below code to get the column value in string:

```
while(dr.Read())
{
    string ut=dr["usertype"].ToString();
    //..........
}
```